# How to correctly deal with escaped Unicode Characters in R e.g. the em dash (—)

Tags: r, unicode

I'm having trouble handling escaped unicode characters in R, specifically those encountered when grabbing information from the MediaWiki API. I would find a JSON string like

```
{"query":{"categorymembers":[{"ns":0,"title":"Banach\u2013Tarski paradox"}]}}
```

Which should be perfectly valid but when read in through `fromJSON()` I get:

```
snip...
[1] "Banach\023Tarski paradox"
```

Initially I thought this was just a problem with RJSONIO, but I encounter similar problems with `scan()` and `readLines()`. My guess is that I am missing something very basic.

I can't actually give a completely reproducible example using *only* R because if I send "em\u2013dash" to a file through write() (or some equivalent function) R will automatically convert the em dash. So here goes. Create a text file named test1 with the following:

```
"em\u2013dash" "em–dash" " em \u2013 dash"
```

Then load up R (for whatever the file path is):

```
> scan( file = "~/R/test1", what = "character", encoding = "UTF-8")
Read 3 items
[1] "em\\u2013dash"    "em–dash"          " em \\u2013 dash"
> readLines("~/R/test1", warn = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
[1] "\"em\\u2013dash\" \"em–dash\" \" em \\u2013 dash\""
```

The added escape character is what causes my problems with `fromJSON()`. I could just strip them out but I'd probably break something else in the process and I imagine there is an easier solution. Thanks.

Here's the session info:

```
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/C/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RJSONIO_0.98-0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.14.1
```

Comment: If you follow the note in `?scan` regarding `allowEscapes` argument to `?Quotes`, it _seems_ to suggest that the parser just doesn't support this in `scan`. But that seems weird to me, so I'm hoping that I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah I saw that too (the bit from `?Quotes`). I also get the same result reading in the content from readLines through a connection or from `getURL()` in RCurl directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug in `RJSONIO` as you can clearly see:

```
> RJSONIO::fromJSON('{"x":"foo\\u2013bar"}')
           x 
"foo\023bar"
```

It works just fine in `rjson`:

```
> rjson::fromJSON('{"x":"foo\\u2013bar"}')
$x
[1] "foo–bar"
```

and to prove it is the correct value:

```
 > Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "C")
[1] "C/C/C/C/C/en_US.UTF-8"
> rjson::fromJSON('{"x":"foo\\u2013bar"}')
$x
[1] "foo<U+2013>bar"
```

In your analysis you got confused by printed string vs actual strings. `print` quotes its content for printing - if you want to see the actual string, you can use `cat` or `charToRaw`. Also `scan` doesn't interpret any escapes, so you get what you give it.

Answer (score 9):

This is not in fact a bug in RJSONIO.  It is designed to expect a string that has been read by R and which has the non-ASCII characters already processed. When one passes it a string with \u, that has not been processed but escaped. 
On my machine with a locale set to en_US.UTF-8, the command

```
fromJSON('{"query":{"categorymembers":[{"ns":0,"title":"Banach\u2013Tarski paradox"}]}}')
```

produces

```
$query
$query$categorymembers
$query$categorymembers[[1]]
$query$categorymembers[[1]]$ns
[1] 0

$query$categorymembers[[1]]$title
[1] "Banach–Tarski paradox"
```

Note that the character is prefixed by `\u` not `\\u`.
See how it appears in R when you simply enter that string.

So the issue is upstream of fromJSON() as to why the string contains \u.
I may add support in RJSONIO for handling such unprocessed strings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Duncan. I can see that if I use your string it does indeed produce exactly what I want. I don't know how to make that happen w/ content read in via RCurl or readLines. That's mostly academic though, as I moved over to rjson and it works fine.

Comment: I'd love to hear more about how to deal with issue in `RJSONIO`. I have some strings with `\\u` prefix, but not sure how to process those before passing to `fromJSON`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the underlying problem is that the `libjson` option [`JSON_UNICODE`](https://github.com/duncantl/RJSONIO/blob/master/src/libjson/JSONOptions.h#L82) is not enabled in `RJSONIO`. However it seems like the problem does not manifest itself when the input is `UTF-8` encoded:

```
library(RJSONIO)
x = "北京填鴨们"
identical(x, fromJSON(toJSON(x)))
# [1] TRUE
```

The problem only appears when the input uses JSON escaped characters. In these cases, `RJSONIO` seems to generate `latin1` output, but doesn't mark set the encoding correctly:

```
x <- fromJSON('["Z\\u00FCrich"]')
print(x)
# [1] "Z\xfcrich"

nchar(x)
#Error in nchar(x) : invalid multibyte string 1
```

For this simple example we can fix it by manually setting the encoding to `latin1`:

```
#Set the correct encoding
Encoding(x) <- "latin1"
print(x)
#[1] "Zürich"
```

However, this of course won't work for characters outside the `latin1` set:

```
#This should be: "填"
fromJSON('["\\u586B"]')
```