# R fromJSON incorrectly reads Unicode from file

Tags: json, r, unicode, character-encoding

I am trying to read json object in R from file, which contains names and surnames in unicode. Here is the content of the file "x1.json":

```
{"general": {"last_name":
"\u041f\u0430\u0449\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e", "name":
"\u0412\u0456\u0442\u0430\u043b\u0456\u0439"}}
```

I use `RJSONIO` package and when I declare the JSON object directly, everything goes well:

```
x<-fromJSON('{"general": {"last_name": "\u041f\u0430\u0449\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e", "name": "\u0412\u0456\u0442\u0430\u043b\u0456\u0439"}}')
x
# $general
# last_name      name 
# "Пащенко" "Віталій"
```

But when I read the same from file, strings are converted to some unknown for me encoding:

```
x1<-fromJSON("x1.json")
x1
# $general
#    last_name         name 
# "\0370I5=:>" "\022VB0;V9"
```

Note that these are not escaped "\u" (which [was discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223795/how-to-correctly-deal-with-escaped-unicode-characters-in-r-e-g-the-em-dash))

I have tried to specify "encoding" argument, but this did not help:

```
> x1<-fromJSON("x1.json", encoding = "UTF-8")
> x1
$general
   last_name         name 
"\0370I5=:>" "\022VB0;V9"
```

System information:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Ukrainian_Ukraine.1251;LC_CTYPE=Ukrainian_Ukraine.1251;LC_MONETARY=Ukrainian_Ukraine.1251;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Ukrainian_Ukraine.1251"
```

Switching to English (Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")) has not changed the situation.

Comment: Is there any reason for you to not use `rjson` package? It works with its function `fromJSON`.

Comment: What @Pascal said, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580601/how-to-correctly-deal-with-escaped-unicode-characters-in-rs-library-rjsonio-whe

Comment: @Pascal, for me it does not, unfortunately (I forgot to mention this in the initial post):  
    `x1<-RJSONIO::fromJSON("x1.json")`  
    `> x1`  
    `$general`  
    `   last_name         name `  
    `"\0370I5=:>" "\022VB0;V9" `  
    
    `> rm(x1)`  
    `> x1<-rjson::fromJSON("x1.json")`  
    `Error in rjson::fromJSON("x1.json") : unexpected character 'x'`  
    `> x1`  
    `Error: object 'x1' not found`

Comment: You need to read the help page. Syntax is different.

Comment: @Pascal, with `x1<-rjson::fromJSON(file="x1.json")` it worked, thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If your file had unicode data like this (instead of its representation)

> ```
> {"general": {"last_name":"Пащенко", "name":"Віталій"}}
> ```

then,

```
> fromJSON("x1.json", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

will work

If you really want your code to work with current file, try like this

> ```
> JSONstring=""
> con  <- file("x1.json",open = "r")
> while (length(oneLine <- readLines(con, n = 1, warn = FALSE)) > 0) {
> JSONstring <- paste(JSONstring,parse(text = paste0("'",oneLine, "'"))[[1]],sep='')
> }
> fromJSON(JSONstring)
> ```

Comment: It works with `fromJSON` from `rjson` package, without manipulation, as I said 3 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

use library("jsonlite") not rjson

```
library("jsonlite")
mydf <- toJSON( mydf, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

will be fine

Comment: the code ```toJSON``` creates a JSON file. It does not read one into R according to the [JSONlite description](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/jsonlite.pdf)